# Getting the path of a physicsBody in Sprite Kit

Tags: sprite-kit

I'm creating an `SKPhysicsBody` in Sprite Kit using `bodyWithPolygonFromPath`. Is there any way for me access the realtime coordinates of the physics body path (relative to the screen)?

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way to access the body's shape path. But you can just retain the path you used to create the body.

That's easy to do, you don't even need to subclass. Simply take the CGPath and put it in a NSMutableDictionary and assign the dictionary to the `userData` property of the node. You can then access the path later on at any time via its key. Remember to release the path when you don't need it anymore.

If your question happened to be about iterating the points in the CGPath, you'll find the answer on SO.

Comment: I actually tried this approach, but unfortunately this will only return the path in its initial position. I need access to the realtime coordinates of the physics body. I've updated the question to clarify this.

Comment: You can (will have to) convert each path point to node space, precisely the node's parent that is using the path for its physics body. In most cases you can just add the node's position to each path point to offset it to the node's position but it's better to use the built-in convert functions.